# Telerik ASP .NET controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I want to create an Organisation chart in my ASP MVC application. We have got licence for telerik AJAX controls - which has Organisation chart control.

Does anyone know if we can use Telerik ASP.NET controls in an MVC application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes.

We've not used the Org Charts but we have used a number of the Telerik asp.net ajax controls (Calendars, Grids and Treeviews for the most recent release) within the views of our MVC project.

You simply need the reference to the Telerik.Web.UI within the view.

Basic code to show the calendar in use:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<asp:Content ID="aboutTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    About Us
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
        Put content here.
    </p>
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <telerik:RadCalendar ID="RadCalendar1" runat="server" TitleFormat="MMMM yyyy" CultureInfo="English (United States)"
        PresentationType="Preview" EnableNavigation="false" EnableMonthYearFastNavigation="false">
    </telerik:RadCalendar>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Telerik have an ASP.NET MVC section which shows use of charts:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

However I think you'll have to check with them as to whether this is part of your licence.

Comment: Thanks Curt. But MVC licence are separate, and since they don't have organisation chart it is difficult to justify buying it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not really answering your question you could not use the Telerik controls but instead use JavaScript libraries offered by Google (for free).

Here is sample code taken from [Google's site](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['orgchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
        data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'}, '', 'The President'],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Kane. But we are looking for advanced features like drag and drop on the charts. I think they are not provided out-of-box by google charts?

Comment: No drag and drop isn't supported out of the box, shame though as it would be a nice feature.